# How do you summon Fishron?

Tags: terraria-mobile

How do you summon Fishron in Terraria Mobile?
I tried to find a Truffle Worm but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Then shouldn't your question be 'How do I find a truffle worm in terraria mobile?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not. Duke Fishron is only available in the PC version of Terraria: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Duke_Fishron as is the Truffle Worm used to summon him

Comment: This awnser is, WORNG. Duke Fishron can be summoned with a Truffle Worm on any platform.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're wrong. A truffle worm can be found in the glowing mushroom biome on Hardmode for mobile but you need a bug net to catch it. However it is very hard to catch.